# OS X WiFi settings via terminal?

Tags: mac-osx, terminal

I manage a large group of macs and they are all connected via ethernet. I would like to disable wifi on them and then require and administrator to change any wifi settings (pretty much what is shown in the picture below)
[image]
Since I manage so many, I would like to push out the setting via remote desktop manager. Is there a command line for these settings? I know that turning off wifi is `networksetup -setairportpower en1 off` but I cant seem to find the settings to require admin privileges.

Comment: I did find one command that lets me disable the hardware altogether and *seems* to require an administrator to renable. Maybe someone can confirm `networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Airport' off`

Comment: I'm not sure why this has close votes? It appears to be about a admining desktops in a professional enviroment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution lies with the less well-known command line tool **airport**.

Which is found in `/usr/sbin` before Snow Leopard (and therefore may already be in your PATH),

For newer OS, it can be found at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources`

In this case, the command you want to issue is the following:

```
sudo airport en1 prefs RequireAdmin=YES
```

The man page is practically empty and issuing *airport --help* actually gives you less usage information than issuing the command without any arguments. The latter gives the following explanation:

> ```
> Usage: airport <interface> <verb> <options>
>
>   <interface>
>   If an interface is not specified, airport will use the first AirPort interface on the system.
>
>   <verb is one of the following:
>   prefs   If specified with no key value pairs, displays a subset of AirPort preferences for
>       the specified interface.
>
>       Preferences may be configured using key=value syntax. Keys and possible values are specified below.
>       Boolean settings may be configured using 'YES' and 'NO'.
>
>       DisconnectOnLogout (Boolean)
>       JoinMode (String)
>           Automatic
>           Preferred
>           Ranked
>           Recent
>           Strongest
>       JoinModeFallback (String)
>           Prompt
>           JoinOpen
>           KeepLooking
>           DoNothing
>       RememberRecentNetworks (Boolean)
>       RequireAdmin (Boolean)
>       RequireAdminIBSS (Boolean)
>       RequireAdminNetworkChange (Boolean)
>       RequireAdminPowerToggle (Boolean)
>       WoWEnabled (Boolean)
>
>   logger  Monitor the driver's logging facility.
>
>   sniff   If a channel number is specified, airportd will attempt to configure the interface
>       to use that channel before it begins sniffing 802.11 frames. Captures files are saved to /tmp.
>       Requires super user privileges.
>
>   debug   Enable debug logging. A debug log setting may be enabled by prefixing it with a '+', and disabled
>       by prefixing it with a '-'.
>
>       AirPort Userland Debug Flags
>           DriverDiscovery
>           DriverEvent
>           Info
>           SystemConfiguration
>           UserEvent
>           PreferredNetworks
>           AutoJoin
>           IPC
>           Scan
>           802.1x
>           Assoc
>           Keychain
>           RSNAuth
>           WoW
>           P2P
>           Roam
>           BTCoex
>           AllUserland - Enable/Disable all userland debug flags
>
>       AirPort Driver Common Flags
>           DriverInfo
>           DriverError
>           DriverWPA
>           DriverScan
>           AllDriver - Enable/Disable all driver debug flags
>
>       AirPort Driver Vendor Flags
>           VendorAssoc
>           VendorConnection
>           AllVendor - Enable/Disable all vendor debug flags
>
>       AirPort Global Flags
>           LogFile - Save all AirPort logs to /var/log/wifi.log
>
> <options> is one of the following:
>   No options currently defined.
>
> Examples:
>
> Configuring preferences (requires admin privileges)
>   sudo airport en1 prefs JoinMode=Preferred RememberRecentNetworks=NO RequireAdmin=YES
>
> Sniffing on channel 1:
>   airport en1 sniff 1
>
>
> LEGACY COMMANDS:
> Supported arguments:
>  -c[<arg>] --channel=[<arg>]    Set arbitrary channel on the card
>  -z        --disassociate       Disassociate from any network
>  -I        --getinfo            Print current wireless status, e.g. signal info, BSSID, port type etc.
>  -s[<arg>] --scan=[<arg>]       Perform a wireless broadcast scan.
>                  Will perform a directed scan if the optional <arg> is provided
>  -x        --xml                Print info as XML
>  -P        --psk                Create PSK from specified pass phrase and SSID.
>                  The following additional arguments must be specified with this command:
>                                   --password=<arg>  Specify a WPA password
>                                   --ssid=<arg>      Specify SSID when creating a PSK
>  -h        --help               Show this help
> ```

Comment: It works fine on macOS Sierra 10.12